# How to resolve "Cannot read property of undefined" in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, automated-tests

I'm newbie in JS and I need to create simple CSV parser for test data. And I have a very strange problem.

This is code of my test:

```
'use strict';

const assert = require('assert');
const HomePage = require('../pages/HomePage');
const csv = require('../tools/CsvReader');

describe('Check if values are correct', () => {

    let dataProvider = csv.readFromCsv("test/resources/places.csv");

    function valuesTest(city, expectedLat, expectedLong) {
        it('Data must match', () => {
            let searchPlace = HomePage
                .open()
                .findByPlaceName(city)
                .getSearchPlace();
            assert.strictEqual(searchPlace.getLatitude(), expectedLat);
            assert.strictEqual(searchPlace.getLongtitude(), expectedLong);
            console.log(dataProvider[0].CITY);
        });
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < dataProvider.length; i++) {
        valuesTest(dataProvider[i].CITY, dataProvider[i].LAT, dataProvider[i].LONG)
    }

});
```

And code of my CSV-reader:

```
'use strict';

const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');

class CsvReader {


    readFromCsv(path) {
        let results = [];

        fs.createReadStream(path)
            .pipe(csv())
            .on('data', (data) => results.push(data));
        return results;
    }

}

module.exports = new CsvReader();
```

And this is my CSV:

```
CITY,LAT,LONG
Kyiv,50.447731,30.542721
Lviv,49.839684,24.029716
Ivano-Frankivsk,48.922634,24.711117
```

The problem is as follows: Why can I use the variable "dataProvider" in the "valuesTest" block and it works correctly and returns the value of the CITY variable, but in the "for" loop I can't use it (variable "dataProvider", "CITY", etc. is unavailable there), although they are located in the same block "describe".

Comment: You have a typo. `dataProvider1[0].CITY` should just be `dataProvider[0].CITY`.

Comment: @Paulpro no, it's not a problem. It works there (I'm already fixed it), but it doesn't work in loop "for".

Comment: Can you put `console.log(dataProvider);` just before your `for` loop starts and tell me what the output is

Answer (score 1):

Your CSV Reader is an asynchronous operation. I suspect your for loop gets executed even before the csv is parsed and value is returned. Try putting your for loop in a function and passing to the readFromCsv function as a callback. Call this function on the data event, where you will be sure to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a callback to `readFromCsv` that will be executed when the `createReadStream` is complete. You can determine when `createReadStream` is complete by listening to its `end` event. (See [csv-parser example code](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser) for instance).

In your case, you could do something like:

```
readFromCsv(path, onEnd) {
    let results = [];

    fs.createReadStream(path)
        .pipe(csv())
        .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
        .on('end', () => onEnd(results));
}

csv.readFromCsv("test/resources/places.csv", function onData(data) {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        valuesTest(data[i].CITY, data[i].LAT, data[i].LONG);
    } 
});
```

You should use the `end` event instead of the `data` event to determine when the stream is complete. If you returned after the first `data` event, you might not get all of the data.

The `data` event is fired once per data chunk. If your data has more than one "chunk", you'll truncate it if you return in the data callback. See [nodeJS docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data) for details on the different event types. You might not notice a difference with small test files, but make a larger file and you'll see the difference.